# Automatic variable expansion in IntelliJ

Tags: java, autocomplete, intellij-idea

I'm working at a Java shop this summer and I'm coming from a C# job. I got super used to just typing `var x = randomMethod();`
In IntelliJ is there anyway to type something like this and then have it automatically expanded to the correct return type after hitting enter. So something like `var x = newStringList();` becomes `List<String> x = newStringList();`

Comment: I've never come across native support for this (although that'd be pretty awesome), but there *might* be a plugin (or you could write it yourself!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rumel, welcome to the java world, and this one is easy...

First, type the method name (start typing it and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to autocomplete, if you like...)

```
newStringList()
```

With your cursor still on the method, or the parenthesis, now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (refactor: *Introduce Variable*) and type the variable name you want (instead of the default, which is `strings`).

```
List<String> strings = newStringList();
```

Good luck!

Comment: Wow, that works and is something I didn't know about IntelliJ, +1!

Comment: No worries. You can look in the IDE settings: *Intentions* to see what sorts of similar actions are available.